# How to Map over a BlankSequence?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, map, sequence

I would like to replace any function `f[x, y, ...]` in a certain expression with the same function with all its arguments squared, i.e. `f[x^2, y^2, ...]`. For example, `2f[x]g[y, z]h[a, b, c]` should be replaced with `2f[x^2]g[y^2, z^2]h[a^2, b^2, c^2]`.

So I tried the following:

```
h[a, b, c] /. f_[x__] -> f @@ (#^2 & /@ List[x])
```

However, this does not work as expected. Instead of `h[a^2, b^2, c^2]` I get `h[a^b^c^2]`. To be sure, I tried this as a test:

```
h[a, b, c] /. f_[x__] -> List[x]
```

The output is `{a, b, c}`, as expected. So if `List[x]` is `{a, b, c}`, I would expect `#^2 & /@ List[x]` to be `{a^2, b^2, c^2}`. To make absolutely sure I'm using `Map` correctly, I tried this:

```
h[a, b, c] /. f_[x__] -> f @@ (#^2 & /@ {a, b, c})
```

The result is indeed `h[a^2, b^2, c^2]` as I expect. So why is the mapping on `List[x]` not working?

Thanks.

Comment: try `h[a, b, c] /. f_[x__] :> f @@ ({x}^2)`  or `h[a, b, c] /. f_[x__] :> f @@ (#^2 & /@ List[x])`?

Comment: try `Trace[h[a, b, c] /. f_[x__] -> f @@ (#^2 & /@ List[x])] // Column` to see why the versions with `->` do not work.

Comment: Thanks, `Trace` is indeed very helpful here. I wasn't aware it existed, but I'm definitely going to use it from now on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) rather than [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html)

```
h[a, b, c] /. f_[x__] :> f @@ (#^2 & /@ {x})

(* h[a^2, b^2, c^2] *)
```

Or more simply

```
h[a, b, c] /. f_[x__] :> f @@ ({x}^2)

(* h[a^2, b^2, c^2] *)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! So just to make sure I understand, the reason `Rule` didn't work is that it first evaluates the rhs to `f[x^2]` and only then applies the rule, while `RuleDelayed` first applies the rule and then evaluates the (correct) rhs?

Comment: From the documentation, "lhs -> rhs evaluates rhs immediately" and "lhs :> rhs or lhs :-> rhs represents a rule that transforms lhs to rhs, evaluating rhs only after the rule is used".